# Running a toy motor using Arduino

Tags: arduino, motor

I have setup a circuit to run a toy motor using Arduino. The fritzing diagram link is below. Motor starts spinning but only after I manually rotate the axis. Could it be because there is not ample current to initially start the motor? Components I am using are as follows:

01) Resistor 330ohm
02) Transistor 2N2222
03) Diode 1N4001
04) Motor (sparkfun, part number: ROB-11696)
05) Arduino

Fritzing diagram: [image]

For my arduino code, I have the following line in the loop function:

```
analogWrite(motorPin, 255);
```

Any ideas why the motor won't start running on it's own and not require the initial manual push??

Thanks.

Comment: It would be better to post the schematic rather than the Fritzing thing - you may get some negative responses here by posting it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the transistor plugged in backwards?

Comment: Does the motor spin by itself when connected directly to the 5V and ground pins?

Comment: A DC motor uses more current to start spinning than when it's already spinning. Your transistor is probably not providing enough current for the motor to start.

Answer (score 1):

Your picture isn't completely clear, but there is a distinct possibility that the transistor is installed backwards.  Normal pinout is: leads pointing Down, flat side towards you, from left to right, pins are Emitter, Base, Collector.

Couple of other things that you should check out:

1) Will your motor run from 5V?

2) Does your 5V power supply have enough current to drive the motor?

3) Is the transistor turning on hard enough?

4) Is the transistor too small?  You haven't mentioned what the specs of the motor are.